# Travis CI run python script

Tags: android, python, travis-ci

I would like to run a `python` script during `Travis` build to generate also a signed `APK`. I have made and placed all the necessary files, but got an error in `Travis`.

```
python: can't open file '/scripts/travis_upload_release_to_github.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I tried also with `sudo` and copied `scripts` folder from root to android based project, because I build `libGDX`. `python2.7` is installed. Where should this folder placed to execute during this process successfully?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Travis build is looking for the scripts directory in the root directory "/" of the build machine's file system. Is the scripts directory in your repository or on the build machine? Have you tried removing the first / from the call to your python script, changing /scripts/...py to scripts/...py?

Comment: This folder is in `GitHub` repository. I haven't tried yet second advice, I will give a try.

Comment: There is another problem now. `This commit doesn't have tag, abort.`

Comment: That is a different problem. Could you accept my answer to the first question and post the new problem as a different question with some more details please?